# ProGuard error: Unknown option '-if' in line 16 of file 'C:\...\proguard.txt'

Tags: android, proguard

I'm having some problems in building an Android app with ProGuard enabled.
This is the complete error:

```
Unknown option '-if' in line 16 of file 'C:\Users\Re\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\86eec96acf5ede717d441880a214115a\proguard.txt'
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting: "true"]
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [enableCrashReporting: "true"]
    }
}
```

And this is my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

I thought it could be a cache problem, so I've tried to Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio and I've tried also to clean the build cache with `gradlew cleanBuildCache`but the problem persists.

If i disable ProGuard the build is successfull. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved removing some unused libraries. 
I don't know which one was causing the problem but it has solved.